# libusb send control transfer without interrupting stream

Tags: c++, linux, alsa, libusb

I need to communicate with an usb audio device. I need to do both control transfers and output audio to the device at the same time.

For the audio output, I use Alsa asoundlib and it works fine. My problem arise when I try to use libusb to send a control transfer (with `libusb_control_transfer`) while streaming audio with Alsa at the same time. With libusb I need to detach the kernel driver and claim the interface (`libusb_detach_kernel_driver`, `libusb_claim_interface`) for the control transfer to work, but that stops the Alsa audio stream, since Alsa uses the kernel driver.

Is there a way to send a control transfer that doesnt requires to claim the interface with libusb?

I would prefer not having to implement the audio playback with libusb.

I am a bit confused about usb, so I apologize if the question is not clear.

Comment: Modify the `snd-usb-audio` driver. What is so special about that device?

Comment: The device store information that I can retreive with the GET_MEM request (https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/audio10.pdf p67 - section 5.2.1.2
Get Request). I didnt find a way to send that request with Alsa, so I used libusb. I will check the `snd-usb-audio`, thank you.